# Django - Javascript - Disable cache on image refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, image, browser-cache

I use, in my template, the following javascript to refresh an image:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#imageactual');
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ data_to_modify.thumbnail.name }}?cachebuster='+Math.floor(Math.random()*100 +1), function(data) {
            var $loader = $(document.createElement('img'));
            $loader.one('load', function() {
                $img.attr('src', $loader.attr('src'));
            });
            $loader.attr('src', data);
            if($loader.complete) {
                $loader.trigger('load');
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

And I display the image with the following html code:

```
<img  id="imageactual" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ data_to_modify.thumbnail.name }}" />
```

In my view I added

```
@never_cache
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
```

and

```
    response = render(request, 'mainsite/modify.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))   
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate proxy-revalidate'
    response['Expires'] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
    response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

But the image is still caching in the browser (Chrome: Version 35.0.1916.153 m)... Do you have any idea how to avoid this?

***EDIT 1:***

```
**Header:**

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/medias/thumbs/odbgelguelteeglndjssastj.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

Comment: Those response headers are related just to the webpage, not to the image. The image is served by another request and that response has its own headers. I think you'll need to modify your webserver settings for given directory/filetypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yedpodtrzitko pointed out, adjusting the cache headers of the web page in Django is pointless.

This part looks wrong:

```
$.get('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ data_to_modify.thumbnail.name }}?cachebuster='+Math.floor(Math.random()*100 +1), function(data) {
```

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ data_to_modify.thumbnail.name }}` is the url of of the image you want to display right? (you use the same url in the html `img` tag)

In that case it doesn't make sense to load that url via ajax.

It seems like you don't need ajax at all, you just need to periodically update the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, with the cachebuster querystring appended:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#imageactual');
    setInterval(function() {
        $img.attr('src', '{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ data_to_modify.thumbnail.name }}?cachebuster='+Math.floor(Math.random()*100 +1));
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably use a much higher number than 100 for cache busting if you're going to be refreshing every 2 seconds.

Comment: @itsadok ...good point, this part was copy & pasted from the OP but I don't see any reason not to just use `Math.random()` directly and control the frequency of update solely from the js interval

Comment: @Anentropic your answer is resolving my problem but the old images are  staying in the browser cache.

Comment: @Erwan to control caching behaviour you need to change headers returned by whatever is serving the image files, i.e. your webserver - Apache, Nginx or whatever